# Cannot manage the fields not filled on Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, axios

I’m making a dynamic form in reactjs. But I have an annoying problem. I would only like to send the fields of the form that are filled out.

To do this, I use this piece of code that allows me to download all datas that are not filled. 
Globally, my code for the sending part is

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
  this.setState({ loading: true });

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ loading: false });
  }, 2000);

 event.preventDefault();
 const {
   name_contact='', name_contact1='', endfr='', endfr_1='',
 } = this.state;

 Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
 if (!this.state[key]) delete this.state[key];
 })

 await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    name: `${name_contact},${name_contact_1} `,end: `${endfr},${endfr_1});
  }
```

On this piece of code, I delete datas from this.state that are null to remove variables with nothing in them.

But my problem is that I don’t know how to handle the fact that a field is empty in axios.get.
I would like to be able to remove from get.axios the variables already deleted by

```
    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
 if (!this.state[key]) delete this.state[key];
 })
```

For example if I do not fill in the name_contact_1 field, I would like axios.get to be

```
    await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    name: `${name_contact}`,end: `${endfr},${endfr_1});
  }
```

or if i'm not puting nothing in endfr

```
await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    name: `${name_contact},${name_contact_1} `,end: `${endfr_1});
  }
```

So my question is : Does anyone have any idea how I can handle this? (It may not be possible with my code structure)
I’m not sure if I’m being clear enough, but if I’m not, tell me and I’ll make sure I change it.

PS: my full code

```
  export default class FormPage extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = initialState;
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

     showMessage = (bool) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({
        showMessage: true
       });
      }, 2000);
     if (this.state.Showing) return;
      this.setState({ Show: true, Showing: true });
     setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ Show: false, Showing: false });
      }, 2000);
     }

     showMessageFalse = (bool) => {
      this.setState({
       showMessage: false
       });
      this.setState(initialState);
     }

     handleChange(event) {
      const InputValue = event.target.value;
      const stateField = event.target.name;
      this.setState({
        [stateField]: InputValue,
      });
      console.log(this.state);
     }

     async handleSubmit(event) {
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({ loading: false });
      }, 2000);

     event.preventDefault();
     const {
       name_contact='',
     } = this.state;
           Object.keys(this.state).forEach(key => {
 if (!this.state[key]) delete this.state[key];
 })
     await axios.post(
      ' MY_endpoint API',
      {
        name: `${name_contact}`);
      }

  render() {

    const { loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <ExpansionPanel title="Contacts" expandedTitle="Contacts" titleIcon="done_all" ><div>
          <Container>
            <div id="normal"><label id='title2'>Detail du contact</label></div><br/>
              <Row align="center">
                <Col id= "color" sm={3}> <label> Name: </label></Col> <Col id= "color" sm={3}><Input placeholder="Nom complet" type="string" name="name_contact" value={this.state.name_contact} onChange={this.handleChange}/><br /> </Col>
              </Row>
          </Container>
          </div>
        </ExpansionPanel>

      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <br /><br /><div id="deb"><Button type="submit" value="Show" onClick={this.showMessageFalse.bind(null, true)} > Update </Button></div>
      </form>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to understand that when you assign the value `const {name_contact=''} = this.state;` And then you later do `delete this.state['name_contact']`, like you've done above, you haven't actually changed the value of the `name_contact` variable. You've changed the value inside the state, but not the value itself.

Secondly, javascript cannot magically create your `name` string like that for you, with a comma only if there are 2 values. You'll have to write a function to do that.

Something like `var name = [name_contact, name_contact1].filter(v =>v).join(',');` The .filter function gets rid of the empty values from the array, and the `.join` turns it into a string with commas between values

So you'll end up with something more like this:

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
  this.setState({ loading: true });

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.setState({ loading: false });
  }, 2000);

 event.preventDefault();
 const {
   name_contact='', name_contact1='', endfr='', endfr_1='',
 } = this.state;


 const name = [name_contact, name_contact1].filter(v =>v).join(',');
 const end = [name_contact, name_contact1].filter(v =>v).join(',');

 await axios.post(
  ' MY_endpoint API',
  {
    name, end
  })
}
```

Comment: little question quickly, the problem with this method is that if I use none of the values in const name = [name_contact, name_contact1]. filter(v =>v). join(',');, the axios will not send anything. For example, if i'm not putting nothing in my the input name_contact and name_contact1, the sending will not work. But if i'm putting only in name_contact it's working fine.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Are you having problem on the server-side with accepting certain values?

Comment: It's not that, it's just, If I put nothing in the fields corresponding to name, it will cancel the sending of all the axios instead of just cancel the sending of name

Comment: Have you tried setting up a breakpoint to figure out what the value of the `name` variable is in those conditions? is it empty? does it throw a javascript error?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't send? Can you check in the `network` tab of developer console?

Comment: okay so the error in the logs of my lambda is ""errorMessage": "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"," I think it's just Dynamodb the problem. But it send the infos so it's not in your code the problem. Thx